# Data.filter not working in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

```
 countImage = data.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length;
```

This statement return error of **Object doesn't support this property or method**, how to fix the problem ? thanks

**Update**, data is get from ajax and it is  an array encoded using json

```
$imgArray[] = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Pv'.$filePadded.'.png';
die(json_encode($imgArray));

data: {'data':issueString}, 
                success: function (data) {
                    countImage = data.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length;


..........
```

Comment: Sorry. missed info. That is an array getting from ajax request

Comment: If it is an javascript array then `filter` method is not available in IE, but it is available in Chrome. It is available in IE 10 though

Comment: Are there any way to change it to ie compatibilie one ? thanks

Comment: @user782104 There's a polyfill near the bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is a javascript array and not a jquery object so you are calling on the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

If you see the compatibility for IE it is mentioned that it is supported in IE9+.

In that page there is also a method to use for browsers that do not support **Array.prototype.filter**

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this == null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.filter()` is not available for IE < 10, it is available in Chrome, FF and [IE 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679973%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). so you need to use some other alternates to filter the array.

You can use [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) instead of fitler method

Code

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, 7, undefined, 8];
alert(a.length);
var arr = jQuery.grep(a, function(n, i){
  return n != undefined;
});

alert(arr.length);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wwPC2/)